# How can I know the caller changed my form inputs values using jQuery backbone.js etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm maintaining a long long java script code edited by many members.(unstructed code)

in HTML page, there are hundreds of inputs. and the inputs' id  named automatically by for loop.

etc. FOR (int i;i<1000;i<++)

In the javascript file . there are many functions will modify the inputs' value in the HTML page.

but now i wanna to trace what javascript function modified the value.
how can i do?

jQuery onchange not work , because it only detected the events from UI change. it can not detected the changes by js code.
backbone.js change method also not works too.

thank you all in advance !!!

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842266/programmatically-manipulating-dom-element-value-doesnt-fire-onchange-event | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773785/why-onchange-doesnt-work | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136617/how-do-i-programatically-force-an-onchange-event-on-an-input

Comment: None of those questions mention Backbone.