# React won't fire the onChange event when I update the value through document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a hidden input field like this :

```
<input type="hidden" value="0" id="selected-committee"
  onChange={this.setSelectedSchool.bind(this)} />
```

I want to fire the `setSelectedSchool` function when this input changes. I change the value of that element in a child component like this :

```
document.getElementById('selected-committee').value = id;
```

This change the value successfully but it does not fire the function. How can I fix this?

Comment: If you are using React, why are you manually fetching element and updating it. You can pass value as a prop in child element.

Comment: @Rajesh Yea I can but the problem is, i'm using a plugin called `Griddle` to load my table. The child component is loaded by that plugin and I have no way to pass props to my child component.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically manipulating DOM element value doesn't fire onchange event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842266/programmatically-manipulating-dom-element-value-doesnt-fire-onchange-event). I think this answers your question. Not sure what that best solution for react is though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe triggering an explicit input event.

```
var element = document.getElementById('selected-committee');
element.value = id;
var event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
element.dispatchEvent(event);
```